# How to autoscroll single line textbox continuous?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I need to write something to autoscroll a text in a single line `TextBox` continuously. Do I need to scroll to caret then set it to first char and start over?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `PathText.SelectionStart = PathText.TextLength;
PathText.ScrollToCaret();
PathText.Refresh();`  The problem is that is not an scrolling text it just jumps to end and i dont know how to start over

Comment: so you are trying to do a marquee scroll?

Comment: basically yes but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

So i found a marquee control and modify it a little and used it instead of textbox

```
public class Marquee : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    private int currentPos = 0;
    private bool mBorder;
    private string mText;

    public string MarqueeText
    {
        get { return mText; }
        set { mText = value; }
    }

    public bool Border
    {
        get { return mBorder; }
        set { mBorder = value; }
    }

    public int Interval
    {
        get { return timer1.Interval * 10; }
        set { timer1.Interval = value / 10; }
    }


    public Marquee()
    {
        // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // TODO: Add any initialization after the InitForm call
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Font.Height);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
                components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Marquee
        // 
        this.Name = "Marquee";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 136);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Marquee_Resize);

    }
    #endregion

    private void Marquee_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height = this.Font.Height;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (mBorder)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(this.ForeColor), 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
        }

        float dif = e.Graphics.MeasureString(mText, this.Font).Width- this.Width;
        if (this.Width < e.Graphics.MeasureString(mText, this.Font).Width)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mText, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
                currentPos, 0);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mText, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
                this.Width + currentPos + dif, 0);

            currentPos--;

            if ((currentPos < 0) && (Math.Abs(currentPos) >= e.Graphics.MeasureString(mText, this.Font).Width))
                currentPos = this.Width + currentPos;
        }
        else 
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mText, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),-dif/2, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

So if the text width is longer than the width of the control the text will be static else the text will auto-scroll